# How to disable the wired connection

Tags: macos, internet

I want to keep my MacBook from going online. I know how to disable wifi.

Can I prevent my MacBook from connecting to the internet if a LAN cable is plugged into it?

Answer (score 1):

To change these preferences on your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Network , then select an Ethernet service in the list on the left.

If there’s a lock  at the bottom left of the Network pane, click it to unlock the preference pane.
[Source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-ethernet-settings-network-preferences-mh11939/mac)